Ubuntu Studio & Qu-32: clipping audio in recording session via USB-B
Hi Ubuntu Studio fans.
I am working with Ubuntu Studio, kernel: 6.8.0-50-lowlatency on a ThinkPad T470. I am able to connect via USB to an Allen&Heath audio mixing console Qu-32 (1.96-Rev4571). In Carla I can see then 32 input nodes coming from the Qu-32. Connecting one of them to Audacity input I can record audio from this channel. But: although the channel in the console has proper leveling (<0dB), the audio recorded by Audacity is clipping extremely. The same happens, when I try a multi track recording in Ardour. Every single track is clipping badly.
The Qu-32 lets me adjust the direct out level for each channel strip. Lowering the output level to -32dB(!) leads to a proper recording on Ubuntu Studio. Unfortunately this workaround is not useful for me, because adjusting the direct out level has a few other downsides (e.g. for the InEar-monitoring for the musicians).
So, how is it possible, that the digital signals <0dB of the 32 channels are clipping on linux-side? I did not find any way to adjust the incoming data in Linux. The alsamixer, showing the Qu-32-"soundcard", tells me: "There are no controls for this soundcard".
Any ideas?
Best Regards
Peter
